# Access Token From Spotify API is the Same One For Each User

Tags: python, flask, spotipy

So during testing, I was able to sign in with 1 spotify account at the login page and receive a correct access code and token. However, when I run and close the app, and run it again, I went on an incognito tab (with no cookies) and was able to successfully sign into a new Spotify account through the same login page (which sends you to authenticate through spotify). But, for some reason, the spotify `API` sent me the same access code and token as the first user.

Thanks for your help!

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, session, redirect, render_template
import time
from os import urandom

# App Initialization
app = Flask(__name__)

# Setup Cookies
app.secret_key = urandom(64)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'A Session Cookie'
TOKEN_INFO = "token_info"

@app.route('/login')
def login():
  sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
  auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
  return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/redirect')
def redirectPage():
  sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
  session.clear()
  code = request.args.get('code')
  token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
  # print(token_info)
  session[TOKEN_INFO] = token_info
  return redirect(url_for('profile', _external=True))

# Universal Functions
def create_spotify_oauth():
  return SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id = 'INSERT CLIENT ID',
    client_secret = 'INSERT CLIENT SECRET',
    redirect_uri=url_for('redirectPage', _external=True),
    scope='user-library-read user-read-recently-played user-read-playback-position playlist-read-collaborative user-read-playback-state user-top-read playlist-modify-public user-read-currently-playing user-library-read playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private',
    )
def get_token():
  token_info = session.get(TOKEN_INFO, None)
  if not token_info:
    raise "exception"
  now = int(time.time())
  is_expired = token_info['expires_at'] - now < 60
  if is_expired:
    sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
    token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(token_info['refresh_token'])
  return token_info

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the function "get_access_token()" returns an access token if it can find any on your system through environment variables, so this isn't even an issue for my application. It's working as intended.